# Does NiFi processor UpdateAttribute support RegEx Negative Lookahead for removing attributes?

Tags: apache-nifi

Working with a flow created by another team where hundreds of attributes are set on flow files that don't all pertain to a particular group of data types.

It does not appear that NiFi supports Regex *negative lookahead* for deleting attributes within the UpdateAttribute processor. Am I mistaking here or is there a special way within NiFi to get it to recognize Negative Lookahead?

Answer (score 1):

This question was [answered by Mark Payne on the Apache NiFi developers mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@nifi.apache.org), I'll post his answer here:

"Yes, the processor makes use of Java Regular Expressions as outlined [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)"